# How to get current date in UTC zone as long value in java 8

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8

How to achieve the following in java 8 date time API

```
long currentDate = Date.UTC(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
System.out.println(currentDate);
```

The above code returned

> 1573171200000

I have tried following

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.toEpochSecond());
```

returned

> 1573212520

Comment: How do you define a "long value"? Is it the count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00Z? Please specify. What is wrong about your second result, which is also a "long value" (in seconds instead of milliseconds)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the `LocalDate` for today, convert it to a `ZonedDateTime` at the start of the day, then convert to `Instant` and get the epoch millis:

```
LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
```

Comment: Or use an instant in the first place, `Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli()`

Comment: You should probably also want `LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)`. Not only because you want the UTC date, but also to make it clear to the reader which time zone’s date you are getting.

Comment: @Holger It’s an option too. Personally I find the version in the answer easier to read, but it’s a matter of taste, so thanks for giving the questioner and everyone a second option to choose from.

Comment: @OleV.V. to me, it looks unnatural to use solutions that bear conversions between different things, when there is an alternative that can operate with the intended thing in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

In fact the two results are correct, just you misunderstand what happen :

In the first statement where you use Date you are defining hour, min, sec as `0`.

Instead for `ZoneDateTime`, you are using `now()` which will gives you the current date time

To get the same time, I guess you need :

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(),
        LocalTime.of(0,0,0), 
        ZoneOffset.UTC);
 Long zdtm = zonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Now both approach return:

```
1573171200000
1573171200000
```

---

[**Ideone demo**](https://www.ideone.com/EcZrAV)

Comment: `long result = Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli();`…

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need ZonedDateTime just use

`System.out.println(Instant.now().toEpochMilli());`

Edit: I misunderstood that you need millies from start of day. YCF_L's answer with Holger's addition is correct.

Regards